# Different type of panda Series elements, numpy ints, during list comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, list-comprehension

I have noticed that in numpy 1.18.4 (and not in previous numpy versions) the element type during list comprehensions is different than accessing element-wise.
For example:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': np.array([1, 2, 3]), 'b': np.array([1, 0, 1])})
var = {type(x) == type(foo['a'][i]) for i, x in enumerate(foo['a'])}
```

I get `var = {False}`. What is the reason for this? Why was it not the case before?

---

Ideally I would like to avoid ZeroDivisionError when dividing by zero but instead get the usual 'inf' produced by numpy.int32, when doing:

```
[0 if x == 0 and z == 0 else x / y for x, y, z in zip(foo['a'], foo['b'], c)]
```

for `c` another array of int32's. Is there any way to do this without re transforming the elements to np.int32 inside the list comprehension?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC what you want, you can use `to_numpy` on the columns from `foo`.

```
foo = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':np.array([0,2,3]), 'b': np.array([1,0,1])})
c = np.array([0,1,1])

[0 if x == 0 and z == 0 else x / y 
 for x, y, z in zip(foo['a'].to_numpy(), foo['b'].to_numpy(), c)]
# [0, inf, 3.0]
```

It works although it raises this `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in long_scalars`

Another alternative is to specify a pandas type like[`pd.Int32Dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Int32Dtype.html) when creating foo:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':np.array([0,2,3]), 'b': np.array([1,0,1])}, 
                   dtype=pd.Int32Dtype())
# or if foo exsit already you use astype with 
# foo = foo.astype(pd.Int32Dtype())

c = np.array([0,1,1])
[0 if x == 0 and z == 0 else x / y for x, y, z in zip(foo['a'], foo['b'], c)]
```

same result

Comment: It works. The question is though why even if you set ```foo['b'] = foo['b'].to_numpy()``` before and then do the other list comprehension (without ```to_numpy()```), still does not work.

Comment: @DiegoFMedina not really sure, to be fair I have numpy 1.18.1 and I get the same result as you with version 1.18.4 about the type difference. I guess it is more how the type is inferred when using enumerate, but I might be wrong

Comment: not really, ```{(type(x), type(y)) for x, y in zip(foo['a'], foo['a'].to_numpy())}``` will give you ```{(int, int32)}``` even after performing ```foo['a']=foo['a'].to_numpy()```.

Comment: @DiegoFMedina yes it is what I tried to say, between `enumerate` on a numpy array directly, or on a pandas series (even if it is has been built from an array), they are two similar but different type of structures and I guess enumerate infer the type for pandas series but not for array. your example shows this perfectly

Comment: @DiegoFMedina see the alternative, if you specify the dtype with pd.Int32Dtype it will work